# How to find user by their id in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I want my bot to be able to give specific roles to specific users declared with their id.
I tried:

```js
const user = bot.users.cache.get(args[2]);
user.roles.add("[role ID]");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem you have here is you are getting a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object instead of a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object.  Users are not associated with a guild and therefore cannot have roles. You typically want to use a user when it doesn't involve guild specific actions (like Direct Messaging).

You cannot get a Member from the Client object directly, however you can get `Client.guilds.cache` and then retrieve the guild, followed by the member from the Guild object using `Guild.members.cache`.

However, most implementations of permission systems like this require some higher permission user to run a command to grant a permission to a new user.  This means you can use the `Message.guild.members.cache.get()` straight from the Message object that invoked your bot command.

Answer (score 7):

If you already have the user's ID, you can fetch the user object using the following code:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client();
let thanos = client.users.fetch('IDHERE');
thanos.then(function(result1) {
    //put your code that uses the result1 (the user object) here
    //for example, you could do var imgURL = result1.displayAvatarURL();
});
```