# Find Member from a Discord Interaction

Tags: discord, discord.js

I looked at Discord API about interactions (see [Interactions structure](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#interaction-object)) and I noticed they don't include the id of the member who invoked them. I want to use Discord.JS to fetch those members, but can't find a guild member without his ID. Is there a way to either get a member without his ID, or get the ID of the member who called a interaction ?

Comment: There's `user` and `member`, what else do you need?

Comment: There is no `id` field in the `member` (https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-member-object)

Comment: But there is in `user` https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object

Comment: Is there a way to fetch a guild member with his user id ?

Comment: But why would you even want that? You already have the member associated with that ID..

Comment: Kicking a user, banning him, giving him a role, mention him etc...

Comment: But you already have the member... What do you think the `member` entry is?

Comment: The `member` in the interaction is just some data sent by discord, and it is not linked to discord js. In order to do manage that user with discord js, I need to fetch it (trought discord.js), thus I need his ID

Comment: I have no knowledge about `discord.js` (you put the wrong tag in the question), but this question should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60676210/how-to-find-user-by-his-id-in-discord-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there appears to be no `id` field for members, you can get it from the `user` object instead.  From there, Discord.js lets you do `<guild>.member('ID here')` to fetch `member` object of a user resolvable from a certain guild, which the ID works as.