# How do i got from user to GuildMember

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So im making a ban slash command using .addUserOption but when i try to get the permissions from the .addUserOption so that the bot doesnt crash when trying to ban an admin i get an error. I already know why, you cant get permissions from a user, only a GuildMember, so how would i go from user to GuildMember?

**CODE:** *(if needed)*

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("ban")
        .setDescription("Bans the specified user!")
        .addUserOption((option) =>
        option
            .setName("user")
            .setDescription('Who do you want to ban?')
            .setRequired(true)
            )
        .addStringOption((option) => 
        option
            .setName('reason')
            .setDescription("Whats the reason youre banning this user?")
            ),
    async execute(client, interaction) {
        if (client.cooldowns.has(interaction.user.id)) {
            let cooldownEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Please wait for the cooldown to end.")
                .setDescription("This is so that the bot doesnt overload")
                .setColor("RED")
               .setFooter("The cooldown is 5 sec")
               .setTimestamp()
          interaction.reply({ embeds: [cooldownEmbed], ephemeral: true });
       } else {
                const user = interaction.member
                const permission = user.permissions.has('BAN_MEMBERS');
                
                let embed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("❌️ | You dont have the permissions to use this command.")
                if(!permission)
                    return interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]})
            
                const tgt = interaction.options.getUser('user')
                
                   let permsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("The user you are trying to ban is an Administrator!")
                    .setColor("RED")
                if (tgt.permissions.has('BAN_MEMBERS')) return interaction.reply({ embeds: [permsEmbed]})
                const reason = interaction.options.getString('reason') || "No reason specified"


       client.cooldowns.set(interaction.user.id, true);

       setTimeout(() => {
           client.cooldowns.delete(interaction.user.id);
       }, client.COOLDOWN_SECONDS * 1000);

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find user by their id in discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60676210/how-to-find-user-by-their-id-in-discord-js) This question is slightly different, but the answer applies I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I checked CollinD's suggestion and i managed to fix the problem. Heres the code if anyone else runs into this problem and needs an answer.

**CODE:**

```js
const tgt = interaction.options.getUser('user');

let permsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('The user you are trying to ban is an Administrator!')
  .setColor('RED');
const guildMember = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(tgt.id);
if (guildMember.permissions.has('BAN_MEMBERS'))
  return interaction.reply({ embeds: [permsEmbed] });
```